Qt 6.7 to open .mdb file, failed at IM002 QODBC: Unable to connect
So I want to read the .mdb file with Qt, and I am stuck at IM002 QODBC: Unable to connect. Already checked the bitness and driver name as in this question: Why am I getting "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" and how do I fix it? and still failed.
Edit and answered: It turns out there is an error in Qt 6.7, the same code runs smoothly on Qt 6.6.3. So anyone out there with the same headache as me, you could check the Qt older version first. Here is the link on Qt Forum that point the error on Qt 6.7
Old question start here:
Checking if the file exists, return true.
Checking if the driver exists and is valid, return true.
Create a dummy file with MS Access 64bit (since mykit is Qt 6.7 64bit to avoid 32bit vs 64bit difference) still creating that error.
Here is my code snippet
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
QString path = "F:\\SKJ Trial\\test data\\Dummy_64bit.mdb";
QString str_comm = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=";

qDebug() << "Is Db valid: " + QVariant(db.isValid()).toString();
qDebug() << "path: " + path;
qDebug() << "Is file exist: " + QVariant(QFile(path).exists()).toString();

str_comm += path;
db.setDatabaseName(str_comm);
qDebug() << "String command: " + str_comm;
db.open();

if(db.isOpen()){
    qDebug() << "Success";
} else {
    qDebug() << "Failed";
    qDebug() << db.lastError().text();
}

and the console log is here:
"Is Db valid: true"
"path: F:\\SKJ Trial\\test data\\Dummy_64bit.mdb"
"Is file exist: true"
"String command: DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=F:\\SKJ Trial\\test data\\Dummy_64bit.mdb"
Failed
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, IM002 QODBC: Unable to connect"

I even try to read a non-existent file to compare the error code, and return same error code (well it should be True since it is a non-existent file). But it makes me think that the function cannot get the file address correctly.
"Is Db valid: true"
"path: F:\\SKJ Trial\\test data\\Dummy_64bi.mdb"
"Is file exist: false"
"String command: DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=F:\\SKJ Trial\\test data\\Dummy_64bi.mdb"
Failed
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, IM002 QODBC: Unable to connect"

Even replacing the backslash with a forward slash also failed to connect.
"Is Db valid: true"
"path: F:/SKJ Trial/test data/Dummy_64bit.mdb"
"Is file exist: true"
"String command: DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};FIL={MS Access};DBQ=F:/SKJ Trial/test data/Dummy_64bit.mdb"
Failed
"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified, IM002 QODBC: Unable to connect"

Could anyone help me if I'm missing something?

Could I answer my question and close it but not marked as duplicate? It turns out there is an error on Qt 6.7, the same code runs smoothly on Qt 6.6.3. So this is an error in Qt version rather tan the code it self.

Question would have to be voted open to accept answers. I doubt that will happen. Either leave as is or you can delete.

It turns out there is an error in Qt 6.7, the same code runs smoothly on Qt 6.6.3. So anyone out there with the same headache as me, you could check the Qt older version first. Here is the link on Qt Forum that points to the error on Qt 6.7
I repeat, there is no error in the code, it is a bug that is present on Qt 6.7. If you find the same problem on other versions, you might search on the Qt forum first, to see if it is a bug.
